# Can WinJS applications run in assigned access mode on Windows 10?

Tags: winjs, cordova-win10

I have a WinJS application (Cordova actually) that we use with Assigned Access mode on Windows 8.1 to provide kiosk functionality. I am trying to upgrade the host tablets (Surface 3) to Windows 10 but there are problems with assigned access.

I have added the windows.aboveLockScreen to the app manifest which has allowed the application to be selected for assigned access. However, whenever the kiosk user logs in, they are redirected back to the login screen.

Reading up on this issue (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt633799(v=vs.85).aspx) it seems that the application is not binding to the "above the lock screen
 view even though it has that capability.

I was able to reproduce this with the HelloCordova starter by adding the extension to the windows 10 appxmanifest:

Is this a limitation of WinJS based applications? or is there a workaround to allow them to run above the lock screen?